# text from search form to variable javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a problem with javascript.
I have a search form in a page with `Id="btn"`.In main.js i have this function:
EDIT:

```
// on page load
$(window).load(function() {

// define api keys
var apiKey = '...';
var apiSecret = 'is ....';

// create a Cache object
var cache = new LastFMCache();

// create a LastFM object
var lastfm = new LastFM({
    apiKey    : apiKey,
    apiSecret : apiSecret,
    cache     : cache
});

var topArtistName = '';

// get weekly artist chart by tag 'trance'
lastfm.tag.getWeeklyArtistChart({tag: 'trance', limit: 6}, {success: function(data){

    // render top weekly artist using 'lastfmTemplateArtists' template
    $('#top_artists').html(
        $('#lastfmTemplateArtists').render(data.weeklyartistchart.artist)
    );

    // define top artist name
    topArtistName = data.weeklyartistchart.artist[0].name;

    // load details of the artist
    lastfm.artist.getInfo({artist: topArtistName}, {success: function(data){

        // render the single artist info using 'lastfmTemplateArtistInfo' template
        $('#top_artist').html(
            $('#lastfmTemplateArtistInfo').render(data.artist)
        );

        // load the artis's top tracks
        lastfm.artist.getTopTracks({artist: topArtistName, limit: 9}, {success: function(data){

            // render the tracks using 'lastfmTemplateTracks' template
            $('#top_tracks').html(
                $('#lastfmTemplateTracks').render(data.toptracks.track)
            );
        }});

    }, error: function(code, message){
        alert('Error #'+code+': '+message);
    }});
  }});
});
```

Now I want search an artist and set the variable `"topArtistName"` with the text that I had input in search form.
I have tried with : `topArtistName=document.getElementById("btn").value` but it doesn't work.
The form is in the same page of the visualization of results.

EDIT: This main.js works good but it searches top Artist from lastfm and populating the page. I want, with a search form, insert a artist name and see it in the page as "top Artist". :)

Comment: You need to get the value of the form field not the form itself.

Comment: Can you show the HTML for the form, also can you fix your code sample, it has some syntax errors, I see a lot of `}});`, finally why are you trying to get the search value on page load? are you prepopulating it somehow?

Comment: EDIT.
With search form i want search an artist to know top tracks...ecc..ecc